# How to target multi-class element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following two tables and jQuery:

```
<table class="grid" />
<table class="grid custom" />

 $('.grid tr:even').addClass('alt');
```

What's happening here is that both tables are being targeted by jQuery.  The first table is fine as the even row is being selected, however the odd is being selected on the second table.

table 1 (grid)
row 1
row 2 - background color (this is right)

table 2 (grid custom)
row 1 - background color (this is wrong)
row 2

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ftk5n/

The problem is that the `$('.grid tr:even')` selector is applying the `:even` criteria to the set of all rows returned by `.grid tr`.  You want the `:even` to be applied on a per-table basis.

Incidentally, you can do this purely in CSS:  http://jsfiddle.net/ahf9q/1/

**Edit**:  Turns out jQuery has the `nth-child` selector that operates just like CSS does.  If you're set on doing this in jQuery rather than CSS, you could do:

```
$('.grid tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alt');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ftk5n/2/

Comment: The problem with the CSS method is that I need for this to work with IE 7/8 and nth-child is not supported in either.  I like the revised jQuery nth-child method, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.grid').each(function(){
    $(this).find("tr:even").addClass('alt');
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: For the record, ``$('.grid').each ...`` is unnecessary.  ``$('.grid').find('tr:even').addClass('alt')`` will perform the ``find`` and ``addClass`` to everything selected by ``$('.grid')``.

Comment: Thank you much, @BishopRook! (epic username btw)  I didn't know that about .find

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.grid').each(function(){
    $("tr:even", this).addClass('alt');
});
```